# Use XmlDictionaryReader to get a value out of a Message

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

I need to get a value out of my WCF Message.  My message has the following value in the debugger:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IBrokerService/SaveAndPrint</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SaveAndPrint xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <contract xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BrokerService.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:ContainerHistoryContracts i:nil="true" />
        <!--Lots of nodes removed for brevity-->
        <d4p1:CurrentBagId>123456</d4p1:CurrentBagId>
        <!--Lots more nodes removed for brevity-->
        <d4p1:WorkStation>TheNeededValue</d4p1:WorkStation>
      </contract>
    </SaveAndPrint>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**But try as I might, I cannot use the XmlDictionaryReader to get the `d4p1:WorkStation` value.  Anyone know how to do this using XmlDictionaryReader?**

NOTE: I tried to use `TypedMessageConverter`, but the clasess generated do not have the attribute of `MessageContract` (they do have `DataContract` though)

Update:  What I have does not work.  But incase you want to see it, here it is:

```
        // Load the message into an xml doc
        var navigator = buffer.CreateNavigator();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream);
        navigator.WriteSubtree(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        xmlWriter.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(memoryStream));
        var workstationElement =
            xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("StringValue",
                @"/s:Envelope[@xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""]/s:Body/SaveAndPrint[@xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""]/contract[@xmlns:d4p1=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BrokerService.Contracts""]/d4p1:WorkStation"));
```

Comment: What does your XML parsing code look like?

Comment: @DVK - Not sure how my broken code will help, but I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            //using unique keys
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "contract").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => ((string)y).Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            //when there are duplicate keys
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2 = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "contract").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => ((string)y).Trim())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());


        }
    }
}
```